# cannot parse from 'QString'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, lxml

I have this code in python 2.7

```
from lxml import etree
def file_dialog(self):
    global root1
    fd = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
    self.f1 = fd.getOpenFileName()
    tree1 = etree.parse(self.f1)
```

when I execute this I get this error 
    tree1 = etree.parse(self.f1)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3310, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:72517)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1814, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106226)
TypeError: cannot parse from 'QString'

this happens only with python 2.7 the same code works with python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution like this:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

self.f1 = fd.getOpenFileName()
    f=open(self.f1)
    xml=f.read()
    f.close()

    tree1 = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
```

Comment: You can use fromstring